# Function pointer to static class member?

Tags: php

If I have a PHP class such as this one:

```
class A
{
    public static function Method()
    {
        return "x";
    }
}
```

I know that I can access this with:

```
echo A::Method();
```

But how would I go about creating a function reference to this method? I tried something like this:

```
$func = "A::Method";
echo $func();
```

But it gives me a run-time error. So, is this possible in PHP? If so, how? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two options:

- `call_user_func("A::Method");`
- `$func = function () { return A::Method(); }; echo $func()`

It's planned (but it's subject to change) to be able to do this with reflection in the next version of PHP:

```
$srm = new ReflectionMethod('A::Method');
$func = $srm->getClosure();
$func();
```

Comment: The `getClosure` method became available with PHP 5.4. Be wary though as about 50% of servers are still using 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Class methods or object methods are called differently than normal functions. Use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func(array('A', 'Method'));
call_user_func('A::Method'); // As of 5.2.3
```